# Craft CMS 3.0 - Log file?

Tags: craft3, error-message, logs, logging

I've been playing around with Craft 3.0 and am just about to develop a site using it. First thing I see when testing my frontpage template is "Internal server error", styled as a Craft error box.

So my question is simple, where is the log file for Craft 3.0? So I can see exactly what might be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/directory-structure.html) the log files are under `/storage/logs` and look for the `web.log` file especially.

If you don't find anything check your webserver logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view the logs in the control panel in Craft 3, like was possible in Craft 2, then you will need to use this plugin: [Logs](https://github.com/ethercreative/logs)

Comment: Why not just using the great Yii2 Debug toolbar?

Comment: You can't view those server logs with the Yii2 Debug toolbar, can you? It was Brad Bell that pointed me to that plugin when I asked this same question via email, so I assume not, or he would have told me to use the toolbar too. :)

Comment: You can't see server logs in your toolbar but Craft logs and as far as I can see the plugin doesn't display server logs as well